# componentDidMount me deja por fuera el alcanze de una variable

Tags: react-native

Tengo una clase `Database`:

```
class Database  { 
    make(){
        return 'ok';
    }
}

export default new Database();
```

En mi `App` componente lo importo de la siguiente manera:

```
import db from 'path/to/Database';

export default class App extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        db.make(); // ERROR
    }

    handlePress = () => {
        db.make(); // Me devuelve correctamente el 'ok'
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }} >
                <Button
                    onPress={this.handlePress}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Si uso los métodos de la clase `Database` mediante el objeto `db` en botones y por fuera del ciclo de vida del componente `App` me funciona todo sin problemas, pero si lo uso dentro del método `componentDidMount()` del componente me lanza el siguiente error

> TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'make' of undefined

¿Cómo lo puedo corregir?

Answer (score 0):

Debería funcionar.

Hice un proyecto en Expo (https://snack.expo.io/SJ18QJM8X) donde hago lo mismo que se menciona en el ejemplo y funciona correctamente: se muestra un alert con lo que devuelve `db.make()`.

¿Chequeaste que no haya ningún error de tipeo?